# Visual Studio 2019 Schema Compare trying to add procedure that already exists

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, schema-compare

I am having this issue where Schema Compare in Visual Studio 2019 has detected that we don't have an SQL Stored Procedure and want to delete it from the live database, but if you can see the attached screenshot, we do have the stored procedure in Visual Studio SQL project.

If I compare the other way around, it tries to add the procedure to the project with a P_S_GetCaseAccountRolesAndCustomers**_1**.sql filename

[image: False detection]

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your file (local) divert from the database (SSMS). For example, your stored procedure is now ALTER instead of CREATE.